# Pictures of the chat software in time, courtesy of balpha

Tags: discussion, chat, user-interface, stack-exchange-history

## Hello World.

[image: Hello World.]

## Lorem Ipsum.

[image: Lorem Ipsum.]

## Hello Barney.

[image: Hello Barney]

## More colours.

[image: More colours]

## More circles

[image: More circles]

## More peoples

[image: More peoples]

## More history

[image: More history]

Comment: [Source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/132076)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance -- what is the point of this post? I don't get it.

Comment: @Jon I just find it interesting to see software take shape.

Comment: I wish more websites did this, I love seeing how UI design changes

Comment: I've never seen this post before. That last one is, uh, an interesting choice.